# CSS - how to get elements of consecutive class

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I have ten li having same class and between this having 4 consecutive class. how I can get the first, second, third and fourth element of consecutive class? with CSS

```css
.abc {
  color: red;
}

.abc+.xyz {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
</ul>`
```

Comment: Could you add text or comments to your code showing which elements you're trying to select?

Comment: Is there a reason that just selecting all the .xyz isn't what you want (i.e. please explain more what you mean by 'consecutive class').

Answer (score 0):

In this case try this

```
.abc.xyz:nth-child(4n - 4) {    
 color: yellow !important;
}
.abc.xyz:nth-child(4n - 3) {
 color: green !important;
}
.abc.xyz:nth-child(4n - 2) {
 color: purple !important;
}
.abc.xyz:nth-child(4n - 1) {
 color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close ! Simply remove `+` character

```css
.abc {
  color: red;
}

.abc.xyz {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
</ul>
```